# How do I read from IsolatedStorage directly into an array of integers?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I am building a Windows Phone game using C#/XNA. In the game, I need to be able to read some data from IsolatedStorage. For this, I create an IsolatedStorageFileStream and then call the Read function. The [msdn documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.isolatedstorage.isolatedstoragefilestream.read%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) for `IsolatedStorageFileStream.Read` states the following:

> The *buffer* parameter can be an instance of the Buffer class, or an array of one of the following types: Byte, SByte, Char, Int16, Int32, Int64, UInt16, UInt32, UInt64, Single, or Double.

However, there is only one overload for the `Read` function, and it takes an array of bytes, not integers or any other type. I realize that the easy workaround is to read the data into a block of bytes, and then use [the BitConverter.ToInt32 function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.bitconverter.toint32%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) in a loop to get the data I want. However, I want to be able to read a block of integers directly from the file into an array of integers, without spending extra intermediate memory, if possible. Any ideas?

Comment: Additionally, I am also curious why the MSDN documentation claims that it is possible to read in an array of integers using the `IsolatedStorageFileStream.Read` function, when it clearly isn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Streams to work with the isolated storage. They make access to isolated storage much easier. This way you can avoid the low level access with bytes and buffers.

A good start:
http://create.msdn.com/en-US/education/quickstarts/Isolated_Storage

Some real good articles about isolated storage (and Windows Phone 7 development):
http://www.windowsphonegeek.com/tips/all-about-wp7-isolated-storage--intro-to-isolated-storage

Comment: From the second link you posted, I found that I can create a [BinaryReader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a4b8basy(v=vs.95\).aspx) from the `IsolatedStorageFileStream` object. The [BinaryReader.ReadInt32](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.binaryreader.readint32(v=vs.95\).aspx) function will suffice for now, although I wish there was a way to read in a whole array of integers, instead of reading them in one by one.